# How to space words automatically with texmaker

Tags: spacing

Whenever I type a sentence in texmaker and i run it to see what it will look like on pdf, it will give me the sentence without the spacing.

For instance, if I write on Texmaker: I love candy. If I run the command, it will give the following:  Ilovecandy. 
Then i write how to fix it. It gives me howtofixit.

Everything I write a sentence, it just removes the space between the words. 
If I write a sentence in word, I just press enter and it will give a space between words. If I do that in latex, it does not do so. 
I do not always to write\thinspace etc for every word. 
Like you will have to write in latex: \thinspace I\thinspacelove\thinspacecandy. You can imagine how annoying it can be.

[image]

Comment: please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'd bet this happens because you're in math mode… Anyway, TeX maker, *a priori*, has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Hi Timothy and Bernard, I send you  a picture. I edited my question. I just want to give me space whenever I write sentences in latex.

Comment: `$` is a command to start math mode, but you have text not mathematics. What was the intended effect of the `$` ? removing them should fix the issue. Note this is unrelated to texmaker which is the editor you used, but latex would make the same output whatever editor you used to make the input file.

Comment: In other words, you do not need to write **text** within `$...$`, since that is exclusively for **math expressions**.

Answer (score 2):

You switched LaTex into *math mode* by surrounding your text with `$`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
   Text with proper spacing.

   $No Spaces In Math Mode$

\end{document}
```